# Schedule lambda invocation from another lambda AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 2 AWS lambda function A and B , both written in Python.
Every time i have A executed , i want B to be executed 3 minutes later.
Is it possible to achieve that? If yes how?

Comment: what triggers A lambda?

Comment: it's triggered by API gateway

Comment: You can use the AWS SDK to create a scheduled cloudwatch event rule (schedule trigger) from inside function A (at the end) to invoke function B and make sure to delete the cloudwatch event rule inside function B

Comment: You should probably check if you need to do it 3 minutes later or if you can trigger it somehow differently. What's the requirement for these 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS step functions to achieve that, [scheduling a serverless workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/scheduling-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-cloudwatch-events/). Step functions allows you to [wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) for a step to be executed.